# File status is always changed, why?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2007, publishing

I'm running Sharepoint Designer 2007 since it was free from Microsoft and it seems that no matter what I do the files in my site are showing up as changed and I need to publish them when in fact they have not changed.

I have publishing set to only publish changed files and I determine changes by comparing source and destination sites.

I host with GoDaddy.

Its just frustrating to make a change in one file and then have Sharepoint tell me all the files have changed.  Should I be using source file timestamp to determine changes?

Regards,

Matthew